# Python: efficient way to find palindrome numbers that are sums of consecutive squares

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, performance

This is a problem from [codewars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/palindrome-integer-composition).

Given an integer N, write a function *values* that finds how many numbers in the interval (1,...,N) are palindromes and can be expressed as a sum of consecutive squares.

For example, *values(100)* will return 3. In fact, the numbers smaller than 100 that have the above property are:

- 5 = 1+4,
- 55 = 1+4+9+16+25
- 77 = 16+25+36

Palindromes that are perfect squares such as 4, 9, 121, etc do not count. Tests are up to N=10^7.

I can solve the problem and pass all the test cases, but I cannot meet the efficiency requirements (the process is killed after 12s).

Am I simply missing some key observation, or there is something wrong with the efficiency of my code below? I broke it down a bit for better readability.

```
from numpy import cumsum

def is_palindrome(n):
    return str(n) == str(n)[::-1]

def values(n):

    limit = int(n**0.5) # could be improved
    pals = []

    for i in range(1,limit):
        # take numbers in the cumsum that are palindromes < n
        sums = [p for p in cumsum([i**2 for i in range(i,limit)]) if p<n and is_palindrome(p)]
        # remove perfect-squares and those already counted
        pals.extend(k for k in sums if not (k in pals) and not (k**0.5).is_integer())

    return len(pals)
```

Note: I'm aware that checking that a number is a perfect square using sqrt(n).is_integer() might not be perfect but should be enough for this case.

Comment: Up to 10^7? Just precompute them all.

Comment: @n.m. Could you be more specific?

Comment: @AdamSmith thanks for the comment. Not sure I understand how that `tuple(p)` works. If I do like that I get `'numpy.int64' object is not iterable`.

Comment: Compute all palindromes that are also sums of consecutive squares offline slowly, then use the computed numbers to write a script that produces the desired answer quickly. Your script should probably contain a line like `numbers=[5,55,77, ....` (continue with precomputed numbers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some mistakes in your code:
1 - You need to use `p <= n` instead of `p < n` ( try `n = 77` )
2 - Use **set** instead of **list** to store your answer, that will speed up your solution.
3 - You don't need to call `cumsum` in the range `[i, limit)` you can accumulate until the sum gets greater than `n`. This will speed up your solution too.
4 - Try to be less "pythonic". Do not fill your code of long and ugly list comprehensions. (This is not a mistake exactly)

This is your code after some changes:

```
def is_palindrome(s):
    return s == s[::-1]

def values(n):
    squares = [0]
    i = 1
    while i * i <= n:
        squares.append(squares[-1] + i * i)
        i += 1
    pals = set()
    for i in range(1, len(squares)):
        j = i + 1
        while j < len(squares) and (squares[j] - squares[i - 1]) <= n:
            s = squares[j] - squares[i - 1]
            if is_palindrome(str(s)):
                pals.add(s)
            j += 1
    return len(pals)
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! Let me check this out. For 1) yes, good catch. For 2) I did not know set would be faster than list. For 3), I also had exactly a list of "squares" that somehow I removed during my attempts, I probably didn't think about filling it up that way. As for being "pythonic" I was driven by the idea that that could speed up the code but I agree, generally I don't like it that way.

Comment: Lists do membership tests for O(n), while sets do it in O(1). Sets are slower to construct, but *crazy* fast to lookup, add, remove, etc. Just note that they are unordered data structures.

Comment: This cuts time by a factor 20: OP's -> 1 loop, best of 3: 607 ms per loop -
@lcastillov -> 10 loops, best of 3: 29.7 ms per loop

Answer (score 4):

Apart from working on computational efficiency, you could improve your algorithm strategy. There is a formula for the sum of all squares s(n)=1²+2²+...+n² = n(n+1)(2n+1)/6. So instead of adding m²+(m+1)²+...+n², you could calculate s(n)-s(m-1). A list for all s(n) to find all possible pairs with `itertools` and subtract them should speed up your program.

[More information about pyramidal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number)

Comment: Unfortunately it would be hard to decide where to stop with your method, because there are solutions with `s(n) > 10000000` even though `s(n)-s(m-1) < 10000000`.

Comment: That's a nice insight, thank you. It's strange I didn't think of that myself.

Comment: hehe, I like that option, I also did not think of it. :)

Comment: @n.m. For a given maximum sum S, an obvious upper limit for n is determined by n² < S. You can further reduce this upper limit, but I see from Tommy's bio that he is capable of doing this himself. We don't want to spoil his codewars fun, do we?

Comment: Ohh sorry, yes that's an obvious limit.

Answer (score 3):

Following @n.m suggestion, you could pre-compute all the values for `n<=10e7`, and return the number of matches:

```
import bisect   

def value(n):
    vals = [5, 55, 77, 181, 313, 434, 505, 545, 595, 636, 818, 1001, 1111, 1441, 1771, 4334, 6446, 17371, 17871, 19691, 21712, 41214, 42924, 44444, 46564, 51015, 65756, 81818, 97679, 99199, 108801, 127721, 137731, 138831, 139931, 148841, 161161, 166661, 171171, 188881, 191191, 363363, 435534, 444444, 485584, 494494, 525525, 554455, 629926, 635536, 646646, 656656, 904409, 923329, 944449, 964469, 972279, 981189, 982289, 1077701, 1224221, 1365631, 1681861, 1690961, 1949491, 1972791, 1992991, 2176712, 2904092, 3015103, 3162613, 3187813, 3242423, 3628263, 4211124, 4338334, 4424244, 4776774, 5090905, 5258525, 5276725, 5367635, 5479745, 5536355, 5588855, 5603065, 5718175, 5824285, 6106016, 6277726, 6523256, 6546456, 6780876, 6831386, 6843486, 6844486, 7355537, 8424248, 9051509, 9072709, 9105019, 9313139, 9334339, 9343439, 9435349, 9563659, 9793979, 9814189, 9838389, 9940499, 10711701, 11122111, 11600611, 11922911, 12888821, 13922931, 15822851, 16399361, 16755761, 16955961, 17488471, 18244281, 18422481, 18699681, 26744762, 32344323, 32611623, 34277243, 37533573, 40211204, 41577514, 43699634, 44366344, 45555554, 45755754, 46433464, 47622674, 49066094, 50244205, 51488415, 52155125, 52344325, 52722725, 53166135, 53211235, 53933935, 55344355, 56722765, 56800865, 57488475, 58366385, 62988926, 63844836, 63866836, 64633646, 66999966, 67233276, 68688686, 69388396, 69722796, 69933996, 72299227, 92800829, 95177159, 95544559, 97299279]
    return bisect.bisect_right(vals, n)
```

You get into the realm of a few hundred nanoseconds...

Comment: I see, thank you for posting. However this is not exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I know Tommy, it was first meant in jest, but upon reflexion, @n.m suggestion is very good: when it comes to the search for performance, hard coding values can sometimes be a good engineering decision; I wanted to put it out there.

Answer (score 2):

you can use some `itertools` tricks to likely speed this up a bit.

```
import itertools

limit = int(n**0.5)  # as before, this can be improved but non-obviously.
squares = [i**2 for i in range(1, limit+1)]
num_squares = len(squares)  # inline this to save on lookups
seqs = [(squares[i:j] for j in range(i+2, num_squares)) for i in range(num_squares-2)]
```

seqs is now a list of generators that build your square sequences. e.g. for `n=100` we have:

```
[ [[1, 4], [1, 4, 9], [1, 4, 9, 16], [1, 4, 9, 16, 25], [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36], [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49], [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64], [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]],
  [[4, 9], [4, 9, 16], [4, 9, 16, 25], [4, 9, 16, 25, 36], [4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49], [4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64], [4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]],
  [[9, 16], [9, 16, 25], [9, 16, 25, 36], [9, 16, 25, 36, 49], [9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64], [9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]],
  [[16, 25], [16, 25, 36], [16, 25, 36, 49], [16, 25, 36, 49, 64], [16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]],
  [[25, 36], [25, 36, 49], [25, 36, 49, 64], [25, 36, 49, 64, 81]],
  [[36, 49], [36, 49, 64], [36, 49, 64, 81]],
  [[49, 64], [49, 64, 81]],
  [[64, 81]],
]
```

If we map `sum` over those we can use `itertools.takewhile` to cut down on the number of equality checks we need to do later:

```
sums = [itertools.takewhile(lambda s: s <= n, lst) for lst in [map(sum, lst) for lst in seqs]]
```

This cuts down the resulting list substantially, while tallying the accumulated sums

```
[ [5, 14, 30, 55, 91],
  [13, 29, 54, 90],
  [25, 50, 86],
  [41, 77],
  [61],
  [85],
  [],
  [],
]
```

We can cut out those empty lists with `filter(None, sums)`, then chain together with `itertools.chain.from_iterable` and pass into `is_palindrome`.

```
def is_palindrome(number):
    s = str(number)
    return s == s[::-1]

result = [k for k in itertools.chain.from_iterable(filter(None, sums)) if is_palindrome(k)]
```

We could do our perfect square check here, too, but we already know that any perfect square *must* be in `squares`. For arbitrarily large `n`, it becomes cheaper and cheaper to build these both into sets and use `set.difference`.

```
result = {k for k in ...}  # otherwise the same, just use curly braces
                           # to invoke set comprehension instead of list
squareset = set(squares)
final = result.difference(squareset)
# equivalent to `result - squareset`
```

Comment: Nice, thanks for taking the time to post the answer. I had actually attempted something similar with takewhile but could not make it work.

Comment: @Tommy no problem. I had fun with the problem! I even [spent some time thinking about it in haskell](https://repl.it/Nz6u/0) and had a lot of fun coming up with that fold to build the consecutive powerset.

Answer (score -2):

A lot of those sites use problems that are relatively easy to solve programatically, but hard to do efficiently. This will be a common problem you run into.

As for a solution, first try to come up with an efficient algorithm. Then, if it doesn't satisfy the time constraint, work on implementing finding less computationally expensing python standard library methods that achieve the same thing. For example, does pals.extend() traverse the entire list every time, or is there a pointer to the last element? If it traverses, then look for a method that doesn't (pals.append() might do this, but I'm not sure